# Very low latency streaming

Tags: audio, video, streaming, latency

I'm looking to stream a live lecture into an overflow lecture theater. I'm planning to stream HD content along with audio from a powerful server with nVidia GeForce GPUs connected to the client via a fiber connection (so hardware/network limitations are no issue) to the overflow theater with very low latency. Because the theaters are within earshot of each other, I need to try to minimalize the latency to as much that there isn't a noticeable delay between the source and destination.

I've tried VLC with RTSP and H.264 but I can't get the latency down from around 1.5 seconds which is incredibly noticeable.

Whats the best way to achieve super-low latency transmission of Audio/Video? I realize this is a broad topic but I thought I'd give it a go here, see if someone has come across a solution to this before :)

Cheers!

Comment: If you want low latency, then don't try to run it through a computer.    I am somewhat surprised that you got it as low as you did.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Zoredache, don't run it through a computer. Perhaps HDMI over Cat6 or something like that would be more suitable.

Answer (score -1):

I am an avid gamer and so streaming is a top priority for me. I use twitch.tv with their built in tools and I can stream with 0s delay (although in my case I prefer 3-10 s delay since I wouldn't want others to know where I am in game). Another easy alternative is [www.own3d.tv](http://own3d.tv) . they have their own boradcasting tool and I think the free version lets you stream without any delay. Try it out and let me know.